# How to find Web element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have attached the [Dom]

[image]

How do I identify the highlighted text message using selenium web driver.

PS: I'm new to selenium,

Comment: Can you send me website where you want to achieve this?

Comment: Go with xpath `//div[@class='message']/span`

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using java. you should using following approach to find element.

As I see the text **The code you've entered is incorrect. Please try again.** inside a `hidden div` and may be this `div` become **highlighted** if you've entered something incorrect.

So you should implement `WebDriverWait` first and wait until this div is visible like below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, implicitWait);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'messageWrapper')]/descendant::span")));
String text = el.getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

And make sure this `element` is not inside any `frame`.

If it's inside a `frame` you need to `switch` that `frame` first then go to find this `element` text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using contains function for `span` with any word from the text *"The code you've entered is incorrect. Please try again."*

```
By.xpath(//div[@class='message']//span[contains(text(), 'incorrect')]);
```

or if the text is uniquely identified, simply try

```
By.xpath(//*[contains(text(), 'incorrect. Please')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Code_ div.message > span"));
```